# ibeacon simulator runs but does not work in backgroundmode ios swift

Tags: swift, ibeacon, ios-background-mode, bluetooth-peripheral

I created a beacon simulator app that advertises the beacon in foreground mode, the app runs in background mode but it does not advertise the beacon. 
Here is my working code

```
import UIKit
import CoreBluetooth
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,CBPeripheralManagerDelegate, CLLocationManagerDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var major: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var minor: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var uuid: UILabel!
    
    var locationManager: CLLocationManager!
    var localBeacon: CLBeaconRegion!
    var beaconPeripheralData: NSDictionary!
    var peripheralManager: CBPeripheralManager!
    let localBeaconUUID = "88b78a0c-34ae-44d0-b30c-001F12345620"
    let localBeaconMajor: CLBeaconMajorValue = 58
    let localBeaconMinor: CLBeaconMinorValue = 20
    let identifier = "myBeacon"
    let txPower = -40
    var timer: Timer!
    
    func centralManagerDidUpdateState(_ central: CBCentralManager) {
        switch central.state {
        case .unknown:
            print("central.state is .unknown")
        case .resetting:
            print("central.state is .resetting")
            
        case .unsupported:
            print("central.state is .unsupported")
            
        case .unauthorized:
            print("central.state is .unauthorized")
            
        case .poweredOff:
            print("central.state is .poweredOff")
            
        case .poweredOn:
            print("central.state is .poweredOn")
            
            peripheralManager.startAdvertising(beaconPeripheralData as? [String: Any] )
            
        }
        
    }
    
    
    
    @objc func initLocalBeacon() {
        if localBeacon != nil {
            stopLocalBeacon()
        }
        let uuid = UUID(uuidString: localBeaconUUID)!
        localBeacon = CLBeaconRegion(proximityUUID: uuid, major: localBeaconMajor, minor: localBeaconMinor, identifier: identifier)
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager.allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates = true
        
        beaconPeripheralData = localBeacon.peripheralData(withMeasuredPower:nil)
        peripheralManager = CBPeripheralManager(delegate: self, queue: nil, options: nil)
    }
    func stopLocalBeacon() {
        peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
        peripheralManager = nil
        beaconPeripheralData = nil
        localBeacon = nil
    }
    
    
    func peripheralManagerDidUpdateState(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager) {
        if peripheral.state == .poweredOn {
            
            peripheralManager.startAdvertising(beaconPeripheralData as? [String: Any] )
        }
        else if peripheral.state == .poweredOff {
            peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
        }
    }
    
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        major.text = "\(localBeaconMajor)"
        minor.text = "\(localBeaconMinor)"
        uuid.text = "\(localBeaconUUID)"
        
        self.timer = Timer.scheduledTimer(timeInterval: 1, target: self, selector: #selector(initLocalBeacon), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
        
    }
   
    
    
    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, willRestoreState dict: [String : Any]) {
        if let services = dict[CBPeripheralManagerRestoredStateServicesKey] as? [CBMutableService],
           let service = services.first {
            peripheral.add(service)
        }
    }
    
    func peripheralManager(_ peripheral: CBPeripheralManager, didAdd service: CBService, error: Error?) {
        if let error = error {
            print("Error advertising service: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            return
        }
        
        let power = NSNumber(integerLiteral: -59)
        beaconPeripheralData = localBeacon.peripheralData(withMeasuredPower: power)
        
        peripheralManager.startAdvertising(beaconPeripheralData as! [String: Any])
    }
    
    func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        print("background")
        peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
        let backgroundTask = UIApplication.shared.beginBackgroundTask(expirationHandler: nil)
        DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 5) {
            self.peripheralManager.startAdvertising([CBAdvertisementDataLocalNameKey: "YourDeviceName", CBAdvertisementDataServiceUUIDsKey: [self.uuid]])
            UIApplication.shared.endBackgroundTask(backgroundTask)
        }
    }
    
    func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {
        peripheralManager.stopAdvertising()
    }
    
}
```

I tried using "CLLocationManager"  allowsBackgroundLocationUpdates and in sign-in & capabilities added

- background mode and enables
- location updates
- uses Bluetooth LE accessory
- background fetch
- background processing
- Acts as a Bluetooth LE accessory

These are the methods I tried that work perfectly in the foreground. Are there any other methods to work the beacon app to work in background mode?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately **iOS does not allow apps to advertise iBeacon in the background.**  This is an intentional operating system restriction.

The only **alternative for background advertising** under user control is to use not iBeacon but OverflowArea advertisements.  I wrote a [blog post](http://www.davidgyoungtech.com/2020/05/07/hacking-the-overflow-area) on how to do this advertising in the background.